# После загрузки файла на Яндекс Диск по Webdav происходят паузы по 60 секунд на каждый мегабайт

Tags: curl, wireshark, webdav, яндекс-диск

Знаю, что это вопрос для [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), но русскоязычных пользователей Яндекса больше, поэтому задаю вопрос здесь. Возможно кто-то проверит на своей системе. Плюс, такого плана вопросы здесь есть.

**ОС**: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

У меня настроен автоматический бэкап файлов на **Яндекс Диск** по протоколу **WebDav**. С недавних пор (около двух недель) он перестал работать. Стал разбираться, понял, что дело не в **Deja-dup**, а в передаче файлов на сервер - загрузка происходит, но очень медленно.

Это видно при загрузке файлов через **nautilus** - открываю `nautilus`, подключась к серверу по адресу `davs://webdav.yandex.ru/` и копирую туда файл. 25 мегабайт грузится долго - около получаса. Окончания загрузки 50 мегабайтного файла не дождался, прервал.

Попробовал загружать файлы напрямую с помощью **curl** и отслеживать происходящее **Wireshark**, и обнаружил следующее:

- На самом деле файл загружается быстро, где-то 1 мегабайт в секунду - как положено.
- После окончания загрузки `curl` выдаёт `Info: We are completely uploaded and fine` и зависает на время равное `количество мегабайт * 60 секунд`. Файл размером 2 мегабайта - две минуты, 3 мегабайта - три минуты. Если в это время заглянуть на Яндекс Диск через Веб интерфейс, то файла ещё нет.
- Далее `curl` завершает работу штатным образом, файл появляется в Яндекс Диске.

**Wireshark** в это время показывает следующее:

**Загрузка файла размером 2 мегабайта** - 2 паузы по 60 секунд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Загрузка файла размером 3 мегабайта** - 3 паузы по 60 секунд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Вопросы:

1. Как это можно объяснить теоретически? Что там происходит? Вроде как сервер по адресу `213.180.204.148` не отдаёт клиенту `192.168.0.106` нужный пакет, поэтому соединение не может завершиться и клиент вынуждент ждать, каждые 60 секунд напоминая о себе с помощью пакета `TCP Keep-Alive`.
2. Можно ли с уверенностью сказать, что дело в сервере Яндекса, а не в моей системе? Насколько я понимаю, `curl` и `nautilus` используют разные механизмы для работы с **WebDav**. `curl` сама по себе, `nautilus` использует [GVFS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS).

---

Файлы заданного размера создаю так:

```
yes 'file_content_one_two_three' | head -c 3M > new_file_3M.txt
```

Загружаю на сервер так:

```
curl --trace-time --trace-ascii curl_output_trace_with_time_ascii.txt -T new_file_3M.txt -u username https://webdav.yandex.ru/Ubuntu_backup/
```

Comment: С середины октября на всех профильных форумах обсуждали, правда я не следил чем закончилось. Поищите «яндекс диск webdav»

Comment: И дело явно не в вашей системе

Comment: @AlexeyTen Посмотрел, проблема у всех: [раз](https://toster.ru/q/677787), [два](https://tertiaroma.livejournal.com/1104465.html). Выходит, прикрыл Яндекс лавочку :). Не пойму только в чём смысл, они ведь позволяют делать тоже самое через своё приложение Яндекс Диск? Ставь приложение и продолжай делать бэкапы. Или есть какой-то подвох?

Comment: как вариант, таким образом принуждают ставить клиента я-диска. что может быть не всегда возможно.